# How to restore the backup with different name

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can i restore the below Amrutha backup with different name through below script.
Could any one please help me doing this.

```
RESTORE database Amrutha
    FROM DISK = 'D:\Amrutha.bak'
    WITH 
    MOVE 'Amrutha' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Amrutha.mdf',
    MOVE 'Amrutha_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Amrutha_log.LDF',
    CHECKSUM;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just specify the new name - as database name and as file names:

```
RESTORE database Amrutha_NEW
FROM DISK = 'D:\Amrutha.bak'
WITH 
  MOVE 'Amrutha' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\AmruthaNEW.mdf',
  MOVE 'Amrutha_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\AmruthaNEW_log.LDF',
CHECKSUM;
```