# Restore Database and change the location for MDF File

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I wont restore my database but the location path is not the same. How can i change this path(partition)?

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] 
FROM  DISK = 'C:\Content.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
NOUNLOAD,  
STATS = 10
```

Error Message:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "F:....\Content01.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15100).
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   File 'Content01' cannot be restored to 'F:....\Content01.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "H:....\Content01_log.LDF" failed with the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this
>   error. Reason: 15105).
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   File 'Content01_log' cannot be restored to 'H:....\Content01_log.LDF'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid
>   location for the file.
>   Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

THANKS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
RESTORE DATABASE [My_Database] 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Content.bak'
WITH MOVE 'MyDatabase_Data' TO 'C:\Data\MyDatabase_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'MyDatabase_Log' TO 'C:\Data\MyDatabase_Log.ldf',
REPLACE,
STATS=10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `WITH MOVE` command of the restore as discussed in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118934/how-to-restore-the-backup-with-different-name).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is here because they are restoring a database with multiple files, each destination file needs a new name. Using SQL Server 2008 R2, the gui does not provide an obvious clue nor does it solve it automatically.